# google api calendar integration doesnt recognize am/pm

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

i have a google calendar integration with php, the problem that im having is that the events are getting inserted in the google calendar, however when an event is after 12m it gets inserted as am when i need it to be PM.

here is the array with the info that im sending:

```
  array(7) {
  ["summary"]=>
  string(12) "Cita MEDICA"
  ["location"]=>
  string(50) "MEDIA - Cra. 349b #825 - 40, Someplace, Around"
  ["description"]=>
  string(21) "Estudio existente"
  ["start"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(18) "2021-05-29T3:00:00"
    ["timeZone"]=>
    string(14) "America/Bogota"
  }
  ["end"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(19) "2021-05-29T03:30:00"
    ["timeZone"]=>
    string(14) "America/Bogota"
  }
  ["attendees"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(16) "alfredo@test.co"
    }
  }
  ["reminders"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["useDefault"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["overrides"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["method"]=>
        string(5) "email"
        ["minutes"]=>
        int(60)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["method"]=>
        string(5) "popup"
        ["minutes"]=>
        int(10)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i see the example in the google calendar site:

```
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
```

te dateTime format is different, i dont understand why -> 17:00:00-07:00 seems to have two parameters.

can someone explain it to me?
thanks!

Comment: Check the calendar itself see what time zone its set to this can some times cause issues with inserting events.

Answer (score 1):

The dateTime of the [event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) is

> a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC3339).

> A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is explicitly specified in timeZone.

**In other words, the `-07:00` is the time zone offset.**

However, since you expplicitly specify the timezone - in your case it is not necessary.